# Grey background cells in excel will not change to no fill

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok, so I've got a bunch of conditional formatting in a spreadsheet that I created several years ago.  For the life of me I cannot figure out why some of the background cells are grey (I want them white/no fill).  There is also a random line in the center of one of the cells that I didn't put there.

You can see in cells M8-M20 and N8-N20, i have a formula.  However, I have the same or similar formula in cells Y&Z8-20. The line I'm referring to is in cells S8&9.

[image: You can see in cells M8-M20 and N8-N20, i have a formula. However, I have the same or similar formula in cells Y&Z8-20. The line I'm referring to is in cells S8&9.]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't analyze anything with a picture.

Comment: What exactly you've tried to get rid of the colour? You've mentioned conditional formatting, what are the rules applied in your highlighted cells? Do you see any difference between any properties of highlighted and not highlighted cells. Does the issue appear on every sheet?...

Comment: What's the safest way to upload the actual sheet?

Comment: Remove the personal information and then upload the file by OneDrive or Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the rule you want to edit, select "Current selection" from the "Show formatting rules for" drop-down list to display the list of all rules for the active cell.